# How to answer confidential interview questions

Tags: interviewing

Recently I had an interview and I was asked questions about my daily work at my current company. They asked about my daily tasks and details of my current project. Which tools, frameworks and technologies we use.

So my question is:

What details I can give for these type of questions?

How do I say, politely, that I cannot answer these questions because they are confidential.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You simply say, "I agreed to keep my employer's business confidential when I went to work for them. It's important to me to be trustworthy."

If you are firm and polite about this, you will identify yourself as someone who is business-savvy.

Of course, it's perfectly reasonable for an employer to ask "What are you doing in your current job? What frameworks and tools are you familiar with? What problems have you solved lately? What would you do differently if you could?

In most cases you should be able to answer questions like that without disclosing your employer's secrets.  For example, if you're in software and you're developing a cross-platform mobile app, you should have plenty to say about how that is done. You can talk about your development, test, and deployment process. You can talk about the standard tools you use. If your employer has custom-built modules in the tool chain you can say "I use a custom tool."

If they ask, "what's the release schedule, who is your product for, and what's the price?" you should say, "I'm sorry, I'm sure you understand it's not my place to talk about that."

Rarely, companies invite people for sham interviews to try to obtain inside information from competitors. But they usually do that by talking to executives and product managers.

Comment: _1 for beating me to the punch with a well thought out, comprehensive answer :)

Comment: My usual response to these questions has been "I'm sorry, but I cannot discuss confidential details concerning current or past employers, and I expect you would desire the same of me if I come to work for you." Rarely do you get to say a negative and spin it to a positive in a single interview sentence. This is one way to do it if you craft it with enough care.

Comment: @WhozCraig This might be an online text thing - but saying that with the "I expect you would desire..." bit on the end actually sounds a little aggressive. I'd just stick with "I'm really sorry, but that's covered by a non-disclosure agreement". The fact that you'd honour the same is then implied, anyway

Comment: @Dan It does indeed have subtle aggression. So did the question that triggered the response in the first place. Otherwise *both* sides of that conversation would be implied.